# UITabBar selected image tint color in interface builder

Tags: xcode5, interface-builder, uitabbar, tintcolor

I'm a bit confused. I found the "selected image tint color" in interface builder in Xcode5. I tried to use it because I really like to do such simple things as color adjustments in IB instead of writing code for it:

[image]

This feature has absolutely no effect. When I change the color, it does not apply to the compiled app.
I already tried clean, clear, deleting the DerivedData directory and starting a fresh project.

Can anybody tell my why this isn't working?

Comment: Same problem, did you manage to fix it?

Comment: Not at all. Actually I found more and more dead features in IB... :/

Comment: In case anyone is still interested, it turns out the solution is to add a user defined attribute to the tab bar. In the identity inspector for the tab bar you can add a key path "tintColor" of type color and select the color you want with a color picker. I discovered this trick from another SO post that I can't find now, otherwise I would cite it.

Comment: Found it: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30175444/change-tab-bar-icon-text-tint-color-from-storyboard

Comment: True. And there are many other workarounds. But still the question: Why doesn't it do anything. It's just a something like 10 versions bug or so