# Change Tab Bar icon/text tint color from Storyboard

Tags: ios, storyboard, uitabbar

I've read about 10 different posts like [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18795117/change-tab-bar-tint-color-ios-7) and they all suggest doing it in your app delegate with code.

Is it even possible to change it from within the storyboard?

Answer (score 5):

For some reason that I'm not clear on, the standard Tint properties in the Attributes Inspector have no effect.

However, if you select the tab bar and open up the Identity Inspector, you can add a custom User Defined Runtime Attribute with a Key Path of `tintColor`, set its type to be Color, and then specify the color that way.

Not the ideal solution I think, but it's the only way I've found so far of being able to control the color from Interface Builder.